# Dynamically loading components in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that is dynamically loading based on the value of the variable "scene". The problem is I have to import and load all the possible scenes under the components, and I have a lot of different possible components. Is it possible for Vue to just dynamically import the passed in scene, or do I need to import everything at the start?

For other reasons, I would prefer not to use a router for this case.

```
<component
  :is="scene"
  v-bind="options"
>
</component>
```

=========

```
import TitleSceneComponent
  from './scenes/common/TitleSceneComponent.vue';

import NarrationSceneComponent
  from './scenes/common/NarrationSceneComponent.vue';

import ChoiceSceneComponent
  from './scenes/common/ChoiceSceneComponent.vue';

  components: {
    TitleScene: TitleSceneComponent,
    NarrationScene: NarrationSceneComponent,
    ChoiceScene: ChoiceSceneComponent,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that you can use a `v-if` that loads different components depending on the data passed.

```
<TitleSceneComponent v-if="booleanValueOrCondition" />
<ChoiceSceneComponent v-if="anotherBooleanValueOrCondition" />
```

This way components can be loaded depending on your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use vue router to something like this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Comment: I would prefer not to use a router for this case as I want this component to handle the different states, and simply change the component as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<component
  :is="sceneComp"
  v-bind="options"
>
</component>
```

=============================

```
computed: {
  sceneComp() {
    return () => import(`./scenes/common/${this.scene}Component.vue`);
}
```